# What does HTMLMediaElement suspend event mean?

Tags: streaming, html5-audio, web-audio-api

In MDN it says "The suspend event is fired when media data loading has been suspended." But what does this actually mean? What are some examples for this event. I'm especially interested in the context of an audio stream.

Answer (score 0):

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/suspend_event

The suspend event occurs when the browser is intentionally not getting media data. This event is triggered when the loading of the media is suspended, suspended means when the download of a media has been completed, or it has been paused for some other reasons

Comment: Sorry, your link does not help, as there is even fewer explanation on what suspend means than on MDN.

Comment: Sorry,
The suspend event occurs when the browser is intentionally not getting media data.

This event is triggered when the loading of the media is suspended, suspended means when the download of a media has been completed, or it has been paused for some other reasons

Comment: Edited answer is basically correct. Further reference: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#resourceSuspend